# Callback parameter for lambdas and member functions

Tags: boost, lambda, c++11

I have this function:

```
void func(boost::function<void(float)> cb){
//do something with cb()
}
```

It works with lambdas and functions.
But it does not allow me to pass a member function or a lambda defined in a member function.

I tried to cast something like this:

```
void class::memberFunc() {
void func((void(*)(float))([](float m){}));
}
```

But it seems like lambda is ignored at calls.
And no idea how to pass a member function too.

Comment: C++ lambdas are function objects, not functions, so casting a lambda to a function pointer is most certainly invoking undefined behavior.

Comment: Ok, so how to pass a lambda to a function?

Comment: @user408141 : Make the function a template (so it doesn't know/care what's being passed to it) or have the function take a `std::function<>` of the appropriate signature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given:

```
struct T {
   T(int x) : x(x) {};
   void foo() {
      std::cout << x;
   }

   int x;
};
```

The object pointer is an implicit first parameter to functions, and this becomes explicit when dealing with `boost::function`.

You can "hide" it from `func` by binding it early:

```
void func(boost::function<void()> cb) {
   cb();
}

int main() {
   T t(42);
   func(boost::bind(&T::foo, &t));
}
```

Or otherwise you can bind it late:

```
T t(42);

void func(boost::function<void(T*)> cb) {
   cb(&t);
}

int main() {
   func(boost::bind(&T::foo, _1));
}
```

See it working [here](http://www.ideone.com/Nn9Tx).